# How to enable Lazarus to compile to Android?

Tags: android, arm, lazarus, fpc

I did not used Lazarus for almost two years. I installed version 1.0.10 and found `Android` as an option for `Target OS` and I decided to test with `ARM` as the `CPU family`, all that in the `Options` window.

But when I exit the `Options` window I receive a message that says *fpc.exe is not compaticle with android-arm*

Then I decided to test with other CPU families but nothing.

Is it really functional or it's there just as a promise?

Comment: Just in case you missed it, see: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Android_Programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is functionality, but it requires a development version of Free Pascal, and is not end user ready/packaged.